# android ImageButton scale and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, layout, scale, imagebutton, aspect-ratio

I have a screen that I'm trying to layout...

Basically, I'm trying to evenly distribute 4 ImageButton objects vertically on a screen... I used this [here](http://andmobidev.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-width-of-view-using-percentage.html) to evenly distribute the items, but now am having a terrible time getting the images to scale but maintain aspect ratio... if I use `scaleType="centerInside"` they don't scale, if I use "fitXY" they don't maintain aspect ratio... here is what the layout looks like:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="0dp"
  android:padding="0dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="5"
  >


        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/share_song" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="left" 
            android:src="@drawable/share_song_button_sel"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="" android:id="@+id/tag_a_song"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/song_check_in_button_sel"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/match_button" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="left" 
            android:background="@drawable/music_match_button_sel"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/friends_button" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/my_friends_music_button_sel"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:padding="0dp" 
          >
        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="65dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:padding="0dp" 
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          >
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/trending_bar"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="top"
          android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the width of the ImageButtons to `fill_parent` and use scaletype `fitStart` for the images that hug the left margin, and `fitEnd` for the ones on the right. Should do the trick, at least as far as your example image goes. You may have some spacing issues if the proportional width of the images exceed the screen width, but it should work for you.

Comment: thx so much for the quick response... i tried that and it doesn't scale the image up... also, if the screen is too small, it won't scale it down.

Comment: though, i've only been only been checking it out in the wysiwyg editor... maybe i shouldn't be trusting that.

Comment: Yeah, don't trust it, it's terrible with that sort of thing, in my experience. Try it on the emulator or on a device.

Comment: oh yeah... that is crazy... the emulator shows it all good... thx so much for the help!

Comment: Is it still true as of today?